# Yii jumping to next page

Tags: yii

I have three different form pages in yii. But I am not able to move to next form page after submitting one. How to do it??

Comment: Hi did you get the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Redirect as shown

```
$this->redirect(array('Step1'));
```