# Yii :: Jump to action of another controller

Tags: yii

For internal redirect I am using $this->redirect('whatever'); 
this is in RegisterController.
I have another controller HomeController.

After completing action in registerController. I want to go to (home/index) which lies in Homecontroller. What I can do? 
And It would be great if you suggest a book or link for yii. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have wriiten "$this->recirect('whatever');". Is it a typo or "recirect" is correct word.

Comment: sorry it was meant to be redirect.

Comment: did you try using $this->redirect(array('home/index')) ?.this is used for redirecting.

Comment: You are duplicating own questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273857/yii-jumping-to-next-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('home/index'));
```